# Add action to option select dynamically created

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add an event to all elements of className, and then add this options selected into an array to send it to the controller.

My problem is that i can't add action to option. First I'm capturing `className` from element:

```
$(".modelSelectedOpt").on("change", function(){
    getSelectedOption();
});
```

After I call the function where I have a `each` that I get all element by className that is selected:

```
 function getSelectedOption(){
    console.log($(this).find(":selected").text());
 }
```

But in first step when i selected option, I don't call to function... I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: The function is adding another change event listener. That second listener won't fire until the second time you select an option. Very bad practice adding event listeners inside other event handlers

Comment: @charlietfl how i can to do this?

Comment: Get rid of the `$(this).on("change"...`. The `each` loop will only run when a change occurs already since that's when you call the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem, in my dynamic select I had an id....

I replaced it with this:

```
<select name="model" class="form-control modelSelectedOpt">
```

in script.js:

```
$(".modelSelectedOpt").on("change", function(e){
        getSelectedOption(e);
    });
```

and now I have an event in all my select and I can get text option selected